# Android listview imageview in listitem gets hidden on scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll, imageview, visibility

I am having this weird problem when trying to dynamically set visibility and image `drawable` of `imageview` in list item. When it initially loads its shows up completely fine but when I scroll it up or down some of the images doesn't show up.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Alarm o = items.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        convertView = View.inflate(mcontxt, R.layout.facelistitem, null);                
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ind = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgind);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (o != null) {
    String name;
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder().append(
            pad(o.GetAlarmHour())).append(":").append(
            pad(o.GetAlarmMinute()));
    if (position == 0) {
        name = "Add Alarm";
    } else if ((o.getAlarmName() != null)
            && !o.getAlarmName().equals("")) {
        name = o.getAlarmName().trim() + " - " + strb.toString();
    } else {
        name = strb.toString();
    }

        //TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgind);
        if (holder.name != null) {
            holder.name.setText(name);
        }

        if (holder.ind != null) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Add Alarm"))
                holder.ind.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (o.IsAlarmOn())
                holder.ind.setImageDrawable(mcontxt.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.alarmon));
            else
                holder.ind.setImageDrawable(mcontxt.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.alarmoff));
        }
        /*
         * if(bt != null){ bt.setText("Status: "+ o.getOrderStatus()); }
         */
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the whole `ListView` turning black? You may need to set:

`android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"`

on your `ListView`.

Otherwise, you may need to provide an alternative to your `INVISIBLE` setting:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Add Alarm")) {
    holder.ind.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.ind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

If you don't do this then recycled views will sometimes be `INVISIBLE` when you don't intend them to be.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set your image to VISIBLE in getView before setting it INVISIBLE/GONE again (if necessary).

In my particular example:

```
    holder.ivImageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.ivImageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (i == 0) {                       
        holder.ivImageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {                                               
        holder.ivImageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```